# HTML form's "action" doesnt carry over my $_GET data

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I have a HTML form that acts as a "confirm deletion?" page and my "Back" button is playing up.

```
$string = "foo.php?id=" . $_POST['fooid'] . "&id2=" . $_POST['barid'];

<!-- ^^ this ends up being "foo.php?id=1&id2=2" -->


<form action='<?php echo $string; ?>'>
    <input type='submit' value='Back'>
</form>
```

the problem is, when the button is pressed it links to foo.php without any of the $_GET data in my string, even though the string contains "id=1&id2=2"

---

P.S I changed the code above so people could better understand it, here is the raw code:

```
<?php
    $string = "xrays.php?id=" . $_POST['visitid'] . "&id2=" . $_POST['patientid'];
?>

<form action='delete.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='xrayid' value='<?php $_POST['xrayid']?>'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Confirm Delete?'>
</form>
<form action='<?php echo $string; ?>'>
    <input type='submit' value='Back'>
</form>
```

Comment: didn't understand can you please explain..

Comment: Add `method='get'` to the second form.

Comment: @AndyG - I don't think that it would help since the default value for form's method is `GET` so even if the OP doesn't mention that attribute - it should treat it as it was `method='get'`. No?

Comment: @OfirBaruch You are probably right, I haven't checked the default, but the method should be present anyway. Added: Yes, default is GET.

Comment: this page displays as two buttons

"confirm delete" and "Back"

the back button is supposed to take me back the previous page with all of the data required in the URL (eg. xrays.php?id=1&id2=2)

on the previous page the id=1 stands for a visitid and id=2 a patientid, stuff from my database which determines what is displayed on that page, i need this information to display the page

Comment: @AndyG adding "method='get'" didn't work sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not the best answer but I would like do something like that:

```
  $string = "foo.php?id=" . $_POST['fooid'] . "&id2=" . $_POST['barid'];

    <!-- ^^ this ends up being "foo.php?id=1&id2=2" -->


    <form action='foo.php'>
<input type="hidden" name="fooid" value ="<php echo $_POST['fooid']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="barid" value ="<php echo $_POST['barid']; ?>" /> 
        <input type='submit' value='Back'>
    </form>
```

This should work properly.

EDIT: change $_GET na $_POST

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the get variable in the form hidden inputs, like so:

```
<form action='foo.php'>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id2" value="2" />
    <input type='submit' value='Back'>
</form>
```

Or you could use a link:

```
<a href="foo.php?id=1&id2=2">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with form submission in general. [W3C: Form Submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13)

Next, let's review $_GET and $_POST. [PHP Manual: $_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) | [PHP Manual: $_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

In summary, inside of your `<form>` tag, use either `method="get"` or `method="post"`. Only one of the superglobal arrays will be populated by successful controls, based upon your method of sending the data. I believe the query string must result from a GET request url (which may be the default), not just a plain string slapped into the `action=""` attribute. I could be wrong about the query string, but you have another problem. You are using two forms on one page. Presently, I think only one form's controls can be submitted successful at a time.

```
<form action='delete.php' method='post'>  <!-- FORM 1 -->
    <input type='hidden' name='xrayid' value='<?php $_POST['xrayid']?>'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Confirm Delete?'>
</form>
<form action='<?php echo $string; ?>'> <!-- FORM 2, add a method="" attribute -->
    <input type='submit' value='Back'>
</form>
```

Upon adding a `method="get"` to form two, it should become clear that a composite `$_POST + $_GET` request is not possible in the *two form approach*, and that you need to start with making a single, monolithic form instead of two modular ones. Using the `type="hidden"` attribute of an `<input />` tag, inside of one form, as in @machineaddict's answer, will help. However, what will really help is if you explicitly use *all the correct attributes* of each tag so that you can spot errors like this in the future.

In a situation like this, it is helpful to know that the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` element would hold the complete query string if your web server received one.

[PHP Manual: $_SERVER](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: It might be interesting to know if `$_GET` or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` would be populated by your query string using the _one form_ approach.